Lenovo laptop keyboard randomly stops functionning
I have exactly the same problem as in Keyboard stops working randomly

Exact same computer (Lenovo legion 15ARH05)
Keyboard randomly stops functioning, begins functioning again perfectly after some days
The laptop is dual boot Win 11 / Manjaro on 2 separate SSDs: when the keyboard stops functionning, it's on both OSs and on BIOS / grub
When it stops working, some keys keep working (fn/screen brightness, fn/airplane mode, fn/touchpad, fn/cpu mode)

Following many recommendations I have

disabled fast boot
reinstalled the BIOS
physically replaced the keyboard with a new one

After those two actions, the keyboard's behavior is exactly the same: sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't
I assume it's not a physical problem:

when it works, it works flawlessly
now I have a brand new keyboard

Any starting point on how to solve the problem ?

If the symptom persists with a new known good keyboard, the problem is the motherboard.

First, the fact the issues happen outside a single OS means the issue is in the hardware. You having the same symptoms in both OSes and in the BIOS and boot environment confirms this.
Second, the fact you've replaced the keyboard and it is still presenting the same symptoms means the problem is outside the keyboard, and is probably in the connections or the mainboard/motherboard.
Third, when dealing with any issue, starting with the simplest possible solution is usually a good idea. With the problem being narrowed down to the mainboard, the first step there is usually to flash the BIOS. You've already done that too, so you're out of easy steps.
Finally, as laptop keyboards usually have their cables integrated into them, you likely replaced bot the keyboard and the cable, and you "inspected" the connection between the cable and the mainboard at the same time, so these are also not likely to be the issue.
Given all your correct steps so far, the next step "up stream" is to replace the mainboard itself.

Not sure about the hardware failure theory: how to explain that sometimes it works flawlessly ? Also I have noticed in the windows device manager that when the keyboard is not working, I have more PIH keyboard entries (up to 4) than when it's ok (one PS2, one PIH). And I have found countless testimonies about the exact same failure for the exact same laptop (google reddit 15ARH05 keyboard)

There are many forms of hardware failure, and many of them are transient or occasional. You're welcome to try replacing the keyboard again. If it's a "known bad" one, getting a replacement one that has the same failure may be expected. However, your problem description indicates it is hardware or firmware, and you've already done what you can to mitigate both these so far as you have, and the next step is replacing the mainboard: that's just where you are.

I finally validated the probable mainboard failure, and specifically the USB bus to which the keyboard is connected. Two reasons for this: on windows the device manager flickering corresponds to repeated plugging - unpluggings of the keyboard (verified with http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_log_view.html). On linux dmesg shows the same repeated plugging - unplugging sequences. The fact that the same behavior appears with two OSes and two keyboards, one of them being brain new points me to the mainboard failure.

Yeah probably it's not the keyboard. Actually there is a certain coil on the motherboard (L23), that might do noise and mess the signals. It's also reported here.
With some soldering skills they managed to fix it.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
